# Should I divide test classes into smaller pieces?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am writing to my project's test codes. I have a some test methods and these methods are very big. It contains many rows and many mock objects.

Mostly these methods use similar code pieces. For this situation I was undecided. Firstly I tried to use @BeforeAll annotation but I must change many structure. I have many instance fields and BeforeAll annotation doesn't allow instance fields so I could change these. For these reasons, I don't use this approach

Secondly I tried to use Before annotation but I have a lot of mock objects. I took many unnecessary stub error.

Lastly I'm thinking, Should I divide to small pieces. Actually I tried and works but I was undecided. **Is this approach suitable for best practices ?**

I searched many resource on internet but I dont find related any usefully content. Mostly I found about private method tests scenario but I didn't any resource about my question

For Instance :

```
    private void initX() { 
       X x = new X();
       x.setSomeField(137L);
       x.setSomeField2("Hi");
       when(YRepository.findByName("Carlos")).thenReturn(x);
    }
    @Test
    void when_sayHelloWorldToBob_expect_takeGoodResponse() {
    // Given 
    initX(); // I used many the same approach.
    initY();
    initZ();
      
    // Some code pieces...

    // When
    String actualResponse = testObject.testMethod(testRequest);

    // Then 
    assertEquals("expectedResponse", actualResponse);
}
```

**I changed to this form and my problem is solved. But Is this approach suitable for best practices ?**

Comment: when it comes to best practices, this ain't best practice. no need to separate this piece of code. You can put everything inside ur test method and everything should just work fine.

Comment: I have written similar codes many times. In this case, Does it not cause code smell? For instance initX() maybe uses in 8 or 9 methods

Comment: Refactoring parts of code that you are using in various places in your tests into methods/functions is usually a good thing, especially if you have seen that it actually works for you and that you like the approach. If you do, keep going down that path.

Comment: thank you for answers. I used setUp method with before annotation and private method divide approachs. I hope its clean :)